# How do I get Java plugin for Chrome?

Tags: java, plugins

I'm new with Ubuntu, and I just downloaded Java from here: http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp

And I am trying to follow this instal guide:

http://java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#selfextracting

But I'm not getting anywhere. After typing `chmod a+x jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin` it says "No such file or directory"

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, 32bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is packaged already in the Ubuntu repositories within the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package which you can install in this way:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Or from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you already have a lot installed and Ubuntu-restriced-extra has conflicts   with software already on your computer, you can follow instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Browser_plugin).

Or just [click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-6-jdk) to open Software Center to where you can install IcedTea6-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you may have is that you must specify which folder you download is. Supposing it is inside Home > Downloads, then the command to set the permission to execute is:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin
```

And the command to execute (install) is:

```
~/Downloads/jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin
```

Comment: Is it really bundled? I thought that just Flash was supplied with Chrome.

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry for the confusion. I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck at this step please follow this in order to continue with the procedure:

1. First: change to the directory on which you have the file by
   entering cd Downloads (in case that you have it on the Downloads
   folder), otherwise use the path in order to gain access to the
   file's folder.
2. Now drop the command in a terminal using `sudo chmod a+x
   ./jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin`

If everything runs fine you will be able to continue with your install guide with no problems.

*Note: running commands into local files differs a little from Windows to linux. And you must specify the full path to the file even if you are currently on it.*

Good luck!