# How to update Oracle Java plugin for Google-chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins

To begin with, I have already read the following solutions:

[Cannot Update Java plugin for Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139319/cannot-update-java-plugin-for-google-chrome)

[How do I get Java plugin for Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122602/how-do-i-get-java-plugin-for-chrome)

[Installing Chrome Java Plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155852/installing-chrome-java-plugin)

[How to install Oracle Java web plugin on Chrome in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151539/how-to-install-oracle-java-web-plugin-on-chrome-in-12-04)

and I hope this does not get marked as duplicate.
I previously un-installed OpenJDK and IceTea plugin and installed `java-sdk 7 update 4`. I made a symbolic link to `libnpjp.so` in my installation folder to `~/.mozilla/plugins`. Everything (including Chrome) was running smoothly as it should have.

Today, when I installed `java-sdk 7 update 5`, I followed same steps as before but now, I get to see this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

I even un-installed and reinstalled chrome, but could not help.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, Chrome Version 21.0.1180.79.

This is really most annoying experience so far.

PS: Kindly don't tell to reinstall Java using some PPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download this shell script from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bleedingedge/) .

Give it Executable permissions. Once you open it will show a list of software. Select Java. It will ask If you want to install openjdk or Sun Java. Select whichever you want. It will work its charm and you're done.

[image: Once you do that this what you will get]

Comment: I will give this a try.

Comment: Note: This script does not work on Saucy, as of this posting.

Answer (score 0):

See this useful [article](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-oracle-java7-jdk7-jre7-firefox-chrome-plugin) for information relating to installing Oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu.

1) Install the Oracle JDK 7
 2) Install the Oracle JRE 7
 3) Install the Firefox/Chrome Oracle Java 7 plugin.

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing, nothing different at all. Still, I am encountering this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the name "plugin" suggests, it's not something you should update "inside" your browser, but "outside" the browser, meaning that the plugin is shared amongst all the browsers (let's say Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.) and could not be updated via the browser itself. You should consider updating the Java installation from your desired package manager, or installer or PPA or whichever you prefer.

Comment: Java is actually up to date. Firefox and Opera are showing it to be up to date. I don't know what is causing Chrome to not realize this fact.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by cleaning the `Chrome` cache.

You enter

```
chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData
```

on the navigation bar. Then check only "Empty the cache" and "Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data" and then click on "clear browser data".